# Cannot store data in database submission form

Tags: php, html, mysql

The user selects a name and it displays a form for submitting some data. I want this data to be stored to the right table according to the selected name. When I click save, I get an error :

Notice: Undefined index: lecturer in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\savelecscores.php on line 20

```
<?php
 include 'connect.php';
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
function resetForm(){
// clearing selects
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
   for (var i = 0; i<selects.length; i++)
  selects[i].selectedIndex = 0;

return false;
}
window.load(resetForm());
  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
     <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Principal</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/principalLecturerForm.php">Lecturer Scores</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/principalServicesForm.php">Services Scores</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/principalLecturerYears.php">Lecturer Over the Years</a></li>

    </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Academic Director</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/ac_directorLecturerForm.php">Lecturer Scores</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/ac_directorServicesForm.php">Services Scores</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/ac_directorLecturerYears.php">Lecturer Over the Years</a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lecturer</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/lecturerForm.php">Lecturer</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/lecLecturerYears.php">Lecturer Over the Years</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Admin</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/adminFormLecturer.php">Save Lecturer Scores</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/adminFormServices.php">Save Services Scores</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../statistics/upload.php">Update Lecturers</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="../../statistics/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
 <br />
 <br />
 <br /> 

    <div id="lecform">

      <form action="savelecscores.php" method="POST">

A1: <input type="text" name="a1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
A2: <input type="text" name="a2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
A3: <input type="text" name="a3" size="5"> <br /><br/>
L1: <input type="text" name="l1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
L2: <input type="text" name="l2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
L3: <input type="text" name="l3" size="5"> <br /><br/>
L4: <input type="text" name="l4" size="5"> <br /><br/>
L5: <input type="text" name="l5" size="5"> <br /><br/>
L6: <input type="text" name="l6" size="5"> <br /><br/>
L7: <input type="text" name="l7" size="5"> <br /><br/>
LEC AVG: <input type="text" name="lavg" size="5"> <br /><br/>
R1: <input type="text" name="r1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
R2: <input type="text" name="r2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
U1: <input type="text" name="u1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
U2: <input type="text" name="u2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
U3: <input type="text" name="u3" size="5"> <br /><br/>

<b>Year:<b/>
<select name="year"> 
<option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option> 
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option></select><br/><br/>

 <b>Unit Name:<b/>
<select id="SelectUnitName" name="unit_name">

    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT unit_name FROM unit");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<option value='".$row['unit_name']."'>".$row['unit_name']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
</form><br /><br/>

<br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit"value="Save" >
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">

</form>
</div>
<br />
<br />
 <div id="footer">

    Copyright e-Statistics 2015

</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Save lecturer scores

```
    <?php

     define('DB_NAME','mydb');
     define('DB_USER','root');
     define('DB_PASSWORD','');
     define('DB_HOST','localhost');

     $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

      if(!$connect){
          die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
      }

     $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connect);

     if(!$db_selected){
          die('Can\'t use'.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
     }

      $lecturer = $_POST['lecturer']; 

     $lecturers = array(
        'dimopoulos',
        'lagkas',
        'kehagias',
       'chrysochoou'
     );

     $value1=$_POST['a1'];
     $value2=$_POST['a2'];
     $value3=$_POST['a3'];
     $value4=$_POST['l1'];
     $value5=$_POST['l2'];
     $value6=$_POST['l3'];
     $value7=$_POST['l4'];
     $value8=$_POST['l5']; 
     $value9=$_POST['l6'];
     $value10=$_POST['l7'];
     $value11=$_POST['lavg'];
     $value12=$_POST['r1'];
     $value13=$_POST['r2'];
     $value14=$_POST['u1'];
     $value15=$_POST['u2'];
     $value16=$_POST['u3'];
     $value17=$_POST['year'];
     $value18=$_POST['unit_name'];

    if (in_array($lecturer, $lecturers) && in_array($year, $years)) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $lecturer  (a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,lavg,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3,year,unit_name) VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12','$value13','$value14','$value15','$value16','$value17','$value18')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
      }

      else {
         echo "No data have been inserted";
      }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no input nor select named "lecturer" in your form, hence `$_POST['lecturer']` is not set.

In your form you should have something like:

```
<select id="SelectLecturer" name="lecturer">
<?php
$lecturers = array(
   'dimopoulos',
   'lagkas',
   'kehagias',
   'chrysochoou'
 );
 foreach ($lecturers as $lecturer){
    echo "<option value='$lecturer'>$lecturer</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
```

Then in your PHP code you will have `$_POST['lecturer']` set with the selected lecturer as value.

**Attention!** Your code is vulnerable to mysql injection. You should use prepared statement (PDO or mysqli), or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string` to sanitize each `$_POST` value before executing query!